# Virtuemart 3 Automatic e-mails/reciepts

Tags: joomla-2.5, virtuemart, emails

Are reciepts automatically sent to the admin e-mail when a customer places an order using Virtuemart 3 and Joomla 2.5? I have seen the registration process which is ok, but I haven't seen any order e-mails arrive in the associated admin inbox. Do I need to install an extension? Or is it to be set somewhere in the config?

Comment: also i have the same issue, i need to add more then one email id with "," sprat ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted this - in the "Checkout" tab in Virtuemart's "Configuration" section where you define at what state of order (pending, confirmed etc) is sent to the admin, you should put in "pending" which sends the e-mail to the admin. However it doesn't work in the Customer bit.